# List extends Collections why?

Tags: java, list, collections

**public interface List extends Collection**

Collection is an interface than why List extends it instead of implements?

Comment: Because `List` is an interface too. `implements` = "provides implementation". Interfaces can't provide implementations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java:

- A **class** can `extends` another
- A **class** can `implements` one or more interface
- An **interface** can `extends` another interface

Ie, in the context of an interface having a "super interface", we use 'extends', not 'implements' as **an interface never implements anything. It extends the existing contract.**

Answer (score 0):

Think of an `interface` as a list of behaviours. An `Animal` can `eat()`, and `move()`. Every animal does it differently, but every animal does it. So an `interface` lists behaviour, and a `class` `implements` those behaviours (defines how an animal moves or eats). So `class Elephant implements Animal`. 
Now this list of behaviours can be extended - a Dog can bark for example. Thats why `interface Dog extends Animal`. And you can create `class Poodle implements Dog`. This class will explain how exactly the Poodle moves, eats and barks.

Moreover a class can be extended - that means that you can add behaviour or override behavoiur of the main class Poodle by exdending it `MinaturePoodle` extends `Poodle`.

To sum up: Class can extend other class or implement an interface(behaviour).
Interface (behaviour) can be extended by other interface or implemented (by creating methods body) by class.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/nogrow.html

Answer (score 0):

`List` is interface, interface does not have definition scope(Since java 7, jdk 8 provides default method).

All the common type of characteristic Collection's is generalized and summarize into `collection` interface which later specialized in different collection's like `List`, `Map` or `Set`.

`List` type of `collection` as same as `Set` & `Map`. And `ArrayList` is implementation of `List` which is also type of `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

From [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

> The List interface places additional stipulations, beyond those specified in the Collection interface, on the contracts of the iterator, add, remove, equals, and hashCode methods. Declarations for other inherited methods are also included here for convenience

Answer (score -1):

List is interface, interface does not have definition scope(Since java 7, jdk 8 provides default method).

while ArrayList,LinkedList is a class and class implements interface.

Basic Hierarchy is
List list = new ArrayList<>();
here list is interface so we can not make a object of it but ArrayList is a class which we can use it .

same principle applied for set,queqe,deque.

MAP is also a inteface but that is stand alone.

Here list extends collection , collection extends iterable .